# CURL Object of type \'System.DBNull\' cannot be converted to type \'System.String

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, cross-domain

Im trying to recieve some response from a website/server, and all i get in return is:

```
System.ArgumentException','Object of type \'System.DBNull\' cannot be converted to type \'System.String
```

my PHP code:

```
$url = 'website';
$fields = array('searchstring' => urlencode('solkrem'), 'menuID' => urlencode(0), 'genses' => urlencode('20170201178577A2F54'), 'removeimages' => urlencode(false));

function httpPost($url, $data)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

echo "<br><br>";

$result = httpPost($url,$fields);

var_dump($result);
```

I also do know, when im trying it trough requestmaker.com with the data and url, i get the response i wanted...

Am i not encoding my fields right, or what could be the cause?

EDIT: some info from requestmaker.com :

Request Headers Sent:

```
POST xxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 75
```

request header recieved:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2017 14:03:20 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Thu, 02 Feb 2017 14:03:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 58300
```

EDIT 3:

I found out, even that the site is asking me to add the details with the & seperator, it wont work if its like this, and it will produce same error:
[image]

But if it looks like this, without the & seperator, it works.  I dont know how its sent, cause its backend PHP on the test page.

Also, if i dont send any fields, it will give same output as the error i have.

[image]

**update 4:**

FRom their website, i saw they are sending it like:

```
'searchstring=solkrem\r\nmenuID=0\r\ngenses=20170201178577A2F54\r\nremoveimages=false
```

would that do something? hmm.

Comment: That error is generated by the other system. It says you are passing a null (nothing) in a variable where it is expecting a string. Have a look at the documentation for the system you are contacting and change your POST accordingly.

Comment: thanks @Andy , but i dont know what system they use.

Comment: updated topic @AndyC

Comment: You don't need to put the `&` in between the fields. http_build_query will do that for you

Comment: @AndyC What if i dont want the &? Can i remove the build and build my own? Or?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is with the "removeimages" parameter...

You have:

```
'removeimages' => urlencode(false)
```

And it should probably be:

```
'removeimages' => urlencode('false')
```

URL encoding a Boolean value of false will not pass anything in the query string and create a null value on the other end.

Comment: Im afraid that that didnt make any difference.

Comment: @maria Try adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));`

Comment: No difference im afraid :|

Comment: I don't think you need to urlencode your data as http_build_query will do that for you. If you want to try and separate the fields with `'\r'` you can change `http_build_query($data)` to `http_build_query($data, '', '\r')`

Comment: So IT will remove the & and replace with \r ?

Comment: The way that an HTTP POST (or GET) normally works is that variable pairs are separated with `&` and the name and value are separated with `=`. The urlencoding, in this case performed by `http_build_query` ensures that if you have those characters in your data they are encoded to 'safe' values that don't interfere with that. I don't see why they would have an api that is breaking that standard.

Comment: Try changing your code to: `$fields = array('searchstring' => 'solkrem', 'menuID' => 0, 'genses' => '20170201178577A2F54', 'removeimages' => false);`